# Ошибка в потоке

Tags: java, javafx

Я учу java лишь 2 недели, и прошу не критиковать за столь глупый вопрос

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import jfxtras.labs.scene.control.gauge.linear.SimpleMetroArcGauge;

class pussy implements Runnable{
@FXML
  public SimpleMetroArcGauge Time;
  String timeS;
  double timeD;
  long time;
  Scanner scn;
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
        scn=new Scanner(new File("src//application//res//Re//TemporaryTimeStart.txt"));                                                                              
    }catch(Exception e){}
        while(scn.hasNext()){
            timeS=scn.nextLine();
        }
        scn.close();
        timeD=Double.parseDouble(timeS);
        time=(long)timeD;

        for(int row=0;row<5;row++){
            Time.setValue(Time.getValue()+0.5);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) time);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
  }     
}
```

Вот запуск потока:

```
     if(ChoiceRe.getText()=="Обычный"){
        System.out.println("Обычный режим запущен");
        normalTime = normalTime/100;
        normalTime=normalTime*60;
        normalTime=normalTime*1000;
        TimeStart=Double.toString(normalTime);
        try {
            x=new Formatter("src//application//res//Re//TemporaryTimeStart.txt");
            x.format(TimeStart);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        x.close();
        Thread t1=new Thread(new pussy());
        t1.start();

    }
```

Компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at application.pussy.run(pussy.java:29)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: 29 строка это какая?

Comment: application.pussy ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Что в этой строчке неправильно?
Time.setValue(Time.getValue()+5.0);

Answer (score 2):

Поля класса, которые явно не инициализированы и имеют ссылочный тип, будут иметь значение `null` по умолчанию. В вашем случае это поле `Time`, поэтому и появляется исключение.